# How to use global variables in Quamotion Pester tests

Tags: pester

I'm using Quamotion and Pester to test my mobile app.

Right now, I find myself having to repeat a lot of parameters (such as usernames and passwords) which I use in my tests.

Is there any way to use global variables in Quamotion/Pester tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define global variables in Pester by prefixing them with `$script:`. Global variables are normally defined at the top of your script.

For example, here's a test which logs in to your app and stores the username as a variable:

```
$script:username = "myuser"

Describe "My App" {
    it "Login" {
        $usernameTextField = Find-Element -xpath "//XCUIElementTypeTextField[@name='username']"
        Set-Value -elementId $usernameTextField -value $script:username

        $loginButton = Find-Element -xpath "//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name='Login']"
        Click-Element -elementId $loginButton
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!